# Is there a way to dynamically call functions from different files in Lua 5.0?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to execute Lua scripts, but the file names of the files that will contain the functions that need to be run are variable.

I've tried looking for ways to include whole folders of Lua files at a time, implement some kind of dependency injection, use variables across files without including the files. All of them have yielded no result.

I'm using a Lua 5.0.2 interpreter that I can't change/replace. I also can't really use LuaRocks modules.

It's for an old game called Zoo Tycoon 2.

Comment: Does `dofile("/path/to/file.lua")` work for you?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `dofile` does appear to exist, but no matter what path I use it can't find the file. Using the same path with `include` does work however, I think `include` might be something related to the game, because I don't find anything regarding it online, I only get results for `require` which also doesn't work.

Comment: `require` gives me `[string "scripts/eventtest.lua"]:6: could not load package \`scripts/testtest.lua' from path \`./?;./?.lua'` and `dofile` gives me `cannot read scripts/testtest.lua: No such file or directory`

Comment: 1) Try absolute path starting from the root of the file system; 2) Try relative path starting from the game directory (it searches Lua scripts according your path starting from the current directory)

Comment: use `print(package.path)` to find out the directory structure where the lua files for your project come from.

Comment: @MikeV. I tried that, I got `[string "scripts/eventtest.lua"]:4: attempt to index global \`package (a nil value)`, however `print(debug.getinfo(1).source)` did work and it gave me `scripts/eventtest.lua`. Zoo Tycoon 2's Lua scripts don't look through your filesystem, but it creates a virtual folder structure based on zip files containing the scripts.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I fear going for an absolute path is not possible, which I described in the comment above this one. I tried the `dofile` which various arguments including `testtest.lua`, `testtest`, `scripts.testtest.lua`, `scripts.testtest`, `scripts/testtest.lua` and `scripts/testtest`. All of them gave me `cannot read <path argument>: No such file or directory`

Comment: Curiously when I `io.open('test.txt', 'w')` it does open a new file inside the root folder of my ZT2 installation which is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Games\Zoo Tycoon 2`.

Comment: now you know where to put `/scripts/`

Comment: @MikeV. I tried the `dofile` with the / at the beginning of the path, but unfortunately it still responds with `cannot read /scripts/testtest.lua: No such file or directory`

Comment: When I do `dofile(debug.getinfo(1).source)` it also says: `cannot read scripts/eventtest.lua: No such file or directory`.

Comment: It also can't find the file when I do `require`. But something that is interesting is that `require` is used by the game. I however can't see if it throws an exception or runs successfully.

Here is the file that uses require: https://github.com/ZtModArchive/Zoo-Tycoon-2-Libraries/blob/34f237e2da346cc05667c4d4695e98ee0e3a81d1/scenario/scripts/patterns.lua

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Games\Zoo Tycoon 2/scripts/testtest.lua`

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys and sorry for dragging you along this uphill battle with this game's strange inner workings, but I fear that dofile and require aren't viable options.

Comment: It seems that `package` can't be found and I think that is why `require` and `dofile` don't work either.